# select data by array. sql

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have three tables:
 NEWS

```
news_id | other fields..
```

TAGS

```
tag_id | other fields..
```

and connecting table TAGS_NEWS

```
tag_id | news_id
```

I want to select data from NEWS table by tags. But the problem is that I should select data by many tags. I can create only one solution of this problem, at first select data by one tag, than from selected data by another tag and so on. But I think it isn't good way of solution of this problem. Maybe is the best way to solve this problem? Maybe I can select necessary data in one query?

For example, NEWS_TAG table:

```
tag_id | news_id
    1   1
    3   12
    4   11
    1   10
    6   1
    7   2
    8   3
    9   3
    10  3
```

Select  data by tags 1,6 
Get the result: `news_id = 1`,
or Select  data by tags 8,9 
Get the result: `news_id = 3`

Comment: what is the problem with `in` clause

Comment: Post your input data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got your problem and I had to solve a similar problem.

Try this solution:

```
select *
from news
join news_tags on news_tags.news_id = news.id
where news_tags.tags_id in(1,2)
group by news.id
having count(*) = 2
```

The only things you have to transmit to this query are the set of `tags_id`'s (in my example `1,2`) and the number of `tags_id`'s (in my example `2`).

I've tested it with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13202).

Answer (score 1):

try this solution

```
select a.* from  NEWS a ,TAGS_NEWS b,TAGS c
where a.news_id = b.news_id
and b.tag_id = c.tag_id
and c.tag_id in ('id0001','id0002')
```

you need to pass only tags ids which is you need.

Comment: this doesn't help, I need the the news with  'id0001' and 'id0002' at same time

Comment: ok , "select a.* from "  change to "select c.tag_id.a.* from ".

Comment: i try, but it doesn't help

Comment: what is your expectation result ? can you give a example  ?

Comment: there is some example in a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from news where new_id in 
(select news_id from tagnews where tag_id in 
(select tag_id from tag where tag_name in (name1,name2)) )
```

maybe it can help.

Comment: the same problem, this doesn't work  I need the the news with 'iname1 and name2'  at same time

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

select news_id from news n join tags_news tn on n.news_id=tn.news_id where tn.tag_id in(1,3,6)

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize sonnywhite solution like the below

```
with tag_ids as ( select tag_id from tags where tag_id in (1,6)),
tag_id_cnt as ( select count(1) cnt from tag_ids)
 select * from news,tag_id_cnt where (news_Id,cnt) in 
 (select news_Id, count(1) from news_tags a, tag_ids b
Where a.tag_id=b.tag_Id
Group by news_Id)
```